# How can i access spring oauth2 client backend api by token instead of jsession in cookie?

Tags: angular, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I know you may confused by the title. Please see the picture.
[image]

I have a backend server secured by spring security and spring security oauth2 client.

```js
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2ClientSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login();
    }
}
```

This works fine when i access localhost:8080/api/get/{id} use JSessionId in cookie.

But i want to use token based authentication so my angular app can access my backend. what should i do?

How can i get a token instead of cookie after login?

please give me some advice, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 parts to this solution as described in my tutorial + code sample:
https://authguidance.com/2017/09/24/basicspa-overview/

Step 1: Use a standards based Authorization Server (AS)

Step 2: use oidc client library in your angular app to redirect the user to the AS to login and get an access token

Step 3: Validate the access token in the API